# Converting a dataset into its corresponding sql queries

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

Looking for ideas to convert a dataset with n number of columns and rows to corresponding sql statements that create an equivalent table and insert the dataset values into the newly created table.

Any pointers for accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: There are a lot of ORM solutions out there, are you wanting to do this from scratch?

Comment: if you already have the `dataset` couldn't you get at `dataset.Tables[0]` from there you could use a lambda statement to store the column.DataType into a string[] for example 
`string[] columnDataTypes = yourDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.DataType).
                                  ToArray();`

Comment: SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM ExistingTable ?